# Values not getting picked up from application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to access values from my application.properties file in the Neo4jConnectionFactory class. I am able to access the properties within my Setup beans class. But, I want to be able to access them from Neo4jConnectionFactory. When I try to do so I get null values. Is this possible?

Applications.properties

```java
neo4j.url = bolt://localhost:7687
neo4j.user = neo4j
neo4j.password = neo4j
```

SetupBeans.java

```java
@Component
public class SetupBeans {
    @Bean
    public Neo4jClient neo4jClient() {
        return new Neo4jConnectionFactory().build();
    }
}
```

Neo4jConnectionFactory.java

```java
@Configuration("neo4j")
public class Neo4jConnectionFactory {

    @Value("${neo4j.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${neo4j.user}")
    private String user;

    @Value("${neo4j.password}")
    private String password;

    public Neo4jClient build() {
        return new Neo4jClient(getUrl(), getUser(), getPassword());
    }
}
```

MyApplication.java

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the package of Neo4jConnectionFactory? What is the package of the class containing \@SpringBootApplication and what does the \@SpringBootApplication annotation look like?

Answer (score 0):

I think this automatically prepends the prefix `neo4j`

```
@Configuration("neo4j")
```

So your `@Value` statments should omit the prefix, like this:

```
    @Value("${url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${user}")
    private String user;

    @Value("${password}")
    private String password;
```